# how to create child records on the basis of parent record field multiselect picklist

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

how to create child records on the basis of parent record field multiselect picklist,if  picklist have 1 value,create single child record.if picklist have 2 values,create 2 records of child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with Account and Contact.

Let's say Account has `MultiSelectPicklist__c` which holds the values like this:

`A1;A2;A3;A4`

Then it will first create a List splitting the by `';'` and then looping through the `lstValues` create a list on Contacts and then insert the Contact List.

```
Account acct = [Select Id, MultiSelectPicklist__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '<record Id>'];

String str = acct.MultiSelectPicklist__c;
List<Contact> lstCon = new List<Contact>();

if(str !=null)
{
    List<String> lstValues = str.split(';');
    for(String pkValue: lstValues)
    {
        Contact con = new Contact(AccountId = acct.Id, LastName='LastName ' + pkValue);
        lstCon.add(con);    
    }
    insert lstCon;
}
```

Comment: i am trying to execute above code,but not getting the value in str/

Comment: List<Opportunity_Splits__c> lstCon = new List<Opportunity_Splits__c>();
    Opportunity oppt= [Select Id, Practice__c FROM Opportunity WHERE  id IN :OpportunityIds];
    system.debug('-----oppt--------'+oppt);
    String str = oppt.Practice__c ;
    system.debug('-----str --------'+str );
    if(str !=null)
    {        List<String> lstValues = str.split(';');
        for(String pkValue: lstValues)
        {      Opportunity_Splits__c con = new Opportunity_Splits__c(Opportunity__c = oppt.Id, Practice__c=pkValue);
            lstCon.add(con);    
        }  insert lstCon;}}

Comment: did you investigate that, which line is giving error? what is get printed in debug log?

Comment: String str = acct.MultiSelectPicklist__c;
this give str =0 in debug,but opportunity have values in multi picklist field.

Comment: I have given an example how to parse, you need to use this kind of code based on your usecase